# Kotlin: How Can I access my Array in my Adapter Function?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am creating an app where the user can add items to their cart. Once the user is done, they can click `Proceed To Cart` which will then open up a new activity showing them the contents of their cart. The contents of the cart are stored in an array and I am passing the array to my second activity using an intent. But cannot access it my MyCustomAdapterClass.

Here is my code:

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.BaseAdapter
import android.widget.ListView
import android.widget.TextView
import java.text.FieldPosition

class Cart : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart)

        val intent = intent
        val listview = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.CartItems)
        listview.adapter = MyCustomAdapter(this)



    }

    private inner class MyCustomAdapter(context: Context): BaseAdapter(){
         private val mContext: Context
         val listOfCartItems = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("CuriseCart")
         val sizeOfCart = listOfCartItems?.size

        init {
             mContext = context
         }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return sizeOfCart!!
        }

        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return position.toLong()
        }

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
            return "Testing"
        }

        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, viewGroup: ViewGroup?): View {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
            val rowFormat = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_custom, viewGroup, false)

            println("Cart Items"+listOfCartItems)
            println("Size of Cart"+sizeOfCart)

            val cruiseTitle = rowFormat.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.cruiseTitle)
            cruiseTitle.text = listOfCartItems?.get(sizeOfCart!!)

            val durationLabel = rowFormat.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.durationLabel)
            val numOfTravelers = rowFormat.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.numOfTravelers)
            val costOfCruise = rowFormat.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.costOfCruise)



            return rowFormat
        }


    }
}
```

I am trying to print whatever is in my array in the listview. I did some testing to see if the values were being passed by printing to console and it is correctly passing the values.

Comment: This is an antiquated way of doing things that is a lot of hassle, both to make your data available to multiple screens and to make it survive screen rotations. I suggest using a single activity with multiple fragments and keeping your array in a ViewModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing your `ArrayList` to your `MyCustomAdapter`.

You can either make your `MyCustomAdapter` class an `inner` class or you can change the constructor of `MyCustomAdapter` to accept your `ArrayList`

For making `MyCustomeAdapter` an `inner class`, just add `inner` keyword to your class.

```
 private inner class MyCustomAdapter(context: Context): BaseAdapter() {
     //use listOfCardItem in the class
     }
```

Or Add `listOfCardItems` to your `MyCustomeAdapter` constructor

```
 private class MyCustomAdapter(context: Context, listOfCartItems: ArrayList<String>): BaseAdapter() {
     //use listOfCardItem in the class
     }
```

You don't have to manually define a property in the class and initialize it with the received value in the primary constructor.

You can define your properties inside the primary constructor with `val` keyword for avoiding the manual initialization of them inside the `init` block.

```
private class MyCustomAdapter(val context: Context, val listOfCartItems: ArrayList<String>)
```

Comment: Thank you this works now!!

Answer (score 0):

***Solution 1:-***

You can make your adapter an **inner class** by adding inner keyword to your class like this

```
    private inner class MyCustomAdapter(context: Context): BaseAdapter() {//your code}
```

and make the list outside of your **onCreate** function.

***Solution 2:-***

just pass your list to the adapter like below

```
    private class MyCustomAdapter(context: Context, listOfCartItems: ArrayList<YourModel>): BaseAdapter() {//your code}
```

In both ways you can access the your list.